# Escape ampersand with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, escaping

I have this SQL-Server query

```
UPDATE qryPETEUR_frmPricingModel() SET G&A = '68442.0000' WHERE comp_id = '10004'
```

Which fails because `Incorrect syntax near '&'`

The query works when I change the field being edited to something without an ampersand, so I think the ampersand is the problem.  Unfortunatly I am stuck having to use the use the field `G&A` and can't change it.

What can I do to get this query working.  I think I have to escape the ampersand, but I can't figure out how.  I have tried adding \ slash in front of it as well as adding `ESCAPE '\'` to the end of the query, but nothing worked.

I am also using Code Igniter if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't escape field names. Put brackets around it:

```
UPDATE qryPETEUR_frmPricingModel()
SET [G&A] = '68442.0000'
WHERE comp_id = '10004'
```

Comment: How can we accomplish the same thing in Oracle SQL?  Oracle does not like the brackets.