# Oracle SQL - Escape ampersand in field name

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I've seen a bunch of related posts, but none yet that resolve my specific question.

In Oracle SQL I need to do something like this:

```
SELECT field1 "Eggs&Cheese"
FROM table1;
```

But it reads the `&Cheese` and wants to do parameter substitution.  I just want the field name to be `Eggs&Cheese`

I saw this post [Escape ampersand with SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820872/escape-ampersand-with-sql-server), but Oracle does not like the bracket [] syntax.

And also [Escaping ampersand character in SQL string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961215/escaping-ampersand-character-in-sql-string), but that is escaping the ampersand in a value string, not a label string.

Comment: My post mentioned specifically that thread is not a solve for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The substitution is related to tool you are using and has nothing to do with column alias.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2aab9edb12e9bd9408ef02fcdb5a97f9)**

---

Depending on the tool you could disable it like "set define off".

Related: [Set define off not working in Oracle SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664916/set-define-off-not-working-in-oracle-sql-developer)  & [How to escape ampersand in TOAD?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52402623/5070879)

Comment: I am using Toad for Oracle.  ```SET DEFINE OFF``` does not resolve.  Any idea how to get around it in Toad?

Comment: @alexherm https://stackoverflow.com/a/52402623/5070879

Comment: Yes.  Works!  Thank you.  Tricky little Toad.  ```In TOAD version 12.120.39 Right click in Editor and Click in Substitution Variable Prompting and select none```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the escape. Works in Oracle SQL Developer.

```
set escape \
SELECT field1 "Eggs\&Cheese" FROM table1;
```

After your work is done you can set it off.

```
set escape off
```

Comment: This does not work for me in Toad.

Comment: It might just be my ignorance, but wouldn't you need to use the escape character in the actual query?

Comment: Wow, I just tried in Oracle SQL Developer and it is working.

Comment: @Dortimer - Yes, I have too. Updated the code. Thanks.